# Summarizing records of a week of statistics

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have a table with the following information.

```
Table: DETAILS
id     received     site
(PK)   timestamp    varchar
```

There are a few thousand entries per day and the site information is hard coded (abc.com, def.com etc). I'd like to get a summary of hits per day for the last week, so that the result would either be:

```
site     count(11/04)   count(10/04)    count(09/04) count(08/04)     
abc.com  300            320             310          320
def.com  200            210             200          220
ghi.com  300            320             310          320
jkl.com  200            210             200          220
```

or:

```
received  abc.com       def.com          ghi.com     jkl.com
11/04     300           320              310         320
10/04     200           210              200         220
09/04     300           320              310         320
08/04     200           210              200         220
07/04     300           320              310         320
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your query with a prepared statemant like this for the last week:

```
-- Generate Query for last week (from Monday to Sunday)
-- store query in @myQuery
--
SELECT CONCAT(
'SELECT site,\n',
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+0) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+0) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+1) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+1) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+2) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+2) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+3) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+3) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+4) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+4) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+5) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+5) day,'%d/%m'),')`\n',
'FROM yourTable\n',
'WHERE received BETWEEN \'',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+5) day,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),'\' AND \'',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1) day,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'),'\'\n',
'GROUP by site\n',
'ORDER by site;'
) INTO @myQuery;

-- Prepare and execute Query
--
PREPARE stmt FROM @myQuery;
EXECUTE stmt;

-- Free Prepare
--
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| site      | count(08/04) | count(07/04) | count(06/04) | count(05/04) | count(04/04) | count(03/04) | count(02/04) |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| abc.de    | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 2            |
| def.at    | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 2            | 0            | 0            |
| first.net | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 1            |
| last.org  | 1            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> -- show table values
MariaDB [test]> --
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * from yourTable;
+----+---------------------+------------+
| id | received            | site       |
+----+---------------------+------------+
|  1 | 2018-04-01 23:59:59 | before.com |
|  2 | 2018-04-02 00:00:00 | first.net  |
|  5 | 2018-04-02 03:00:00 | abc.de     |
|  6 | 2018-04-02 04:12:00 | abc.de     |
|  7 | 2018-04-04 07:00:00 | def.at     |
|  8 | 2018-04-04 07:07:00 | def.at     |
|  9 | 2018-04-08 23:59:59 | last.org   |
| 10 | 2018-04-09 00:00:00 | after.ch   |
+----+---------------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> -- Generate Query for last week (from Monday to Sunday)
MariaDB [test]> -- store query in @myQuery
MariaDB [test]> --
MariaDB [test]> SELECT CONCAT(
    -> 'SELECT site,\n',
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+0) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+0) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+1) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+1) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+2) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+2) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+3) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+3) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+4) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+4) day,'%d/%m'),')`,\n'
    -> 'sum(if(date(received) = \'', DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+5) day),'\',1,0)) as `count(',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+5) day,'%d/%m'),')`\n',
    -> 'FROM yourTable\n',
    -> 'WHERE received BETWEEN \'',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())+5) day,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),'\' AND \'',DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1) day,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'),'\'\n',
    -> 'GROUP by site\n',
    -> 'ORDER by site;'
    -> ) INTO @myQuery;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> -- Show query - only to review
MariaDB [test]> --
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @myQuery;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @myQuery                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT site,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-08',1,0)) as `count(08/04)`,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-07',1,0)) as `count(07/04)`,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-06',1,0)) as `count(06/04)`,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-05',1,0)) as `count(05/04)`,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-04',1,0)) as `count(04/04)`,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-03',1,0)) as `count(03/04)`,
sum(if(date(received) = '2018-04-02',1,0)) as `count(02/04)`
FROM yourTable
WHERE received BETWEEN '2018-04-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-08 23:59:59'
GROUP by site
ORDER by site; |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> -- Prepare and execute Query
MariaDB [test]> --
MariaDB [test]> PREPARE stmt FROM @myQuery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [test]> EXECUTE stmt;
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| site      | count(08/04) | count(07/04) | count(06/04) | count(05/04) | count(04/04) | count(03/04) | count(02/04) |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| abc.de    | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 2            |
| def.at    | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 2            | 0            | 0            |
| first.net | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 1            |
| last.org  | 1            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            | 0            |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> -- Free Prepare
MariaDB [test]> --
MariaDB [test]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: Oh wow, and here I was thinking this was a simple SELECT statement. This worked PERFECTLY, thank you **so** much! :-)

Comment: @Mr Panther - you can also put it in a "simple" Query, but then you cant set the row alias with the actual date in it

Comment: Panther, if you or any future readers need a little help with prepared statements, I made a tool not too long ago that labels every part of it, lets you see how one is constructed (for different types of queries), and then lets you copy the formatted code over to your project :) it's over at my site http://wbr.bz/QueryPro and the thing i made to help my own team practice prepared stmts